# SQL Server views getting timeout periodically

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, timeoutexception

I have a serious problem which prevents me from using views in SQL Server. The issue is that the views when used, I am getting timeout exception very often. And surprisingly whenever I just alter the view, the error disappears for some time.

My sample view is as follows - let's say I have two tables, `Product` and `ProductTranslation`. The `Product` table contains master details of product table and `ProductTranslation` contains translation of product names and descriptions in other languages.

```sql
CREATE VIEW myview 
AS
    SELECT
        p.productid AS productId,
        COALESCE(pt.prName, p.prName) AS prName,
        COALESCE(pt.prDesc, p.description) AS prDesc,
        '2' AS langId
    FROM
        Product p 
    LEFT JOIN 
        ProductTranslation pt ON p.productId = pt.productId AND pt.langId = 2
        
    UNION

    SELECT
        productId, prName, description AS prDesc, '1' AS langId  
    FROM
        itecom.Product
```

The product table and productTranslation table get updated frequently.

I will use this view in many joins to get the expected results:

```sql
SELECT ... 
FROM
    <joins> 
LEFT JOIN
    myview pt ON p.productId = pt.productId AND pt.langId = @lang
```

Initially it works as expected but after sometime the join queries will throw timeout exception. And as said, once I alter the view statement (without modifying any code of view), the join query again work smoothly.

Could anyone please figure out the issue here. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend against the use of views if you are looking for performance. The issue is generally two-fold: 1) The developers don't understand the cost of using a view so they use it inappropriately, and 2) Some database engines are not great at optimizing queries that use views. The case only worsens when the view happen to have aggregations, subqueries, data materialization, unions, and/or outer joins. And worse of all, developers forget to save the views' DDL in the source code repository, so they are "unversioned".

Comment: I'll mention that nested views are often a performance problem but that doesn't seem to be the case based on the info in your question. The symptom fast, then slow until the view is recreated suggests classic parameter sniffing, which can be a problem with or without views. One way to avoid that is to add an `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint to outermost queries (i.e. those that use the view).

Comment: There is no problem with views or optimizing them in any version of SQL Server since 2000.  ***Views Do Not Cause Performance Problems***, but using them poorly along with bad queries, unindexed tables, etc. do.

Comment: As @DanGuzman an outer `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` is probably you only possible quick fix here.  To go any deeper, we would need to see the table definitions and indexes of both the query and view, and ideally the query plans when it is "good" vs "bad".  I will note that you've got a UNION in this view which frequently can be the source of inconsistent performance.

Comment: And change 'UNION' to 'UNION ALL' as there are no duplicates between the queries.

Comment: A quick fix here would be to change your UNION to a UNION ALL.  Because you have identified the LangId column as either a 1 or 2 both queries will be unique/distinct and therefore the UNION is causing an unnecessary sort to be included.

Comment: As to the actual issue of why it works and then suddenly stops working - I would suspect that has to do with statistics.  When you alter the view you force SQL Server to regenerate statistics and you now get a better plan.  Make sure you have a process in place to update statistics more frequently.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.  You know there are no duplicates *between* the subqueries because `langId` is different.  So you can probably use:

```
SELECT p.productid AS productId,
       COALESCE(pt.prName, p.prName) AS prName,
       COALESCE(pt.prDesc, p.description) AS prDesc,
       '2' AS langId
FROM Product p LEFT JOIN 
     ProductTranslation pt
     ON p.productId = pt.productId AND pt.langId = 2        
UNION ALL
SELECT productId, prName, description AS prDesc, '1' AS langId  
FROM itecom.Product;
```

If you need to remove duplicates *within* the subqueries, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT`.  This allows the optimizer to use indexes specific to each subquery for the duplication remove.